# How to combine multiple rows of data into one row and then add text in between from another data set using an arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 data sets with non-exact matches so I can't use a simple vlookup or even a vlookup with a wildcard.

Here's a visual of the data and the desired result: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TB8NtedUpehmsRG1-NJ0RzvfopFu9PlsgcOVfrUorzA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={FILTER(A3:A, A3:A<>""), FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>"")}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can I ask what could be done instead if the parameters were mismatched and not in the same order?

Comment: @Jeff it would depend on what extent. they could be matched up with a common element or otherwise, without any link, they need to be treated individually

Comment: I updated the example spreadsheet to illustrate what I mean. And sorry I meant: if the number of rows were mismatched and not in the same order. I noticed the filter function broke when I added extra rows to one of the data sets, and the Quantities no longer matched up with the correct Description as well when the data is reordered.

Comment: @Jeff see your sample sheet

Comment: I've reordered both data sets so the Quantities don't match the Description anymore.